How to write the device address when using HAL_I2C_Mem_Write and HAL_I2C_Mem_Read functions?
I want to use the HAL_I2C_Mem_Read() function to read a control register of ZSC31050 and then configure the control register by using the HAL_I2C_Mem_Write() function.
The default device address of ZSC31050 is 78hex.
It is supposed to be shifted left by 1 bit.
So while using the write function is it supposed to be f0 and while using read function as f1?

Yes, that is basically correct. For I2C using 7-bit addresses, the first 7 bits of the first byte are the address, and the least-significant bit is the read/write bit.
So as you said, you need to shift the address left by one, and then set the least significant bit for a read, and leave it clear for a write.
See e.g. this good description of I2C from Texas Instruments. (Particularly section 3.)

You're right on your understanding of I2C addresses, but not right about STM32 I2C functions.
You do not need to shift the address manually. HAL_I2C_Mem_Write() and HAL_I2C_Mem_Read() already do that for you.
See I2C HAL module driver for STM32F4
